# Unexpected capacity exceeded

Tags: tikz-pic

The following code gives me an unexpected capacity exceeded error, and I don't understand why...

```
 \[\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5, yscale=5.5]
 
 node (1) at (0,0){
 $\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.6, yscale=0.6]

 \tikzset{morphlabel/.style={draw=black, thin, rectangle, minimum width=7pt, fill=white, 
 font=\scriptsize}}

 \node[morphlabel] at (0, 0) {$a$};
 \end{tikzpicture}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}\]
```

What feels really odd to me is that I use almost identical code at other places, and don't get any error message?

Comment: Please extend this to a full example others can copy and test as is. That said, using `tikzpicture` inside tikz picture is asking for trouble. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The first `node` is missing a backslash.

Comment: Oups... I was afraid I had made such a dumb mistake. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        
        \tikzset{morphlabel/.style={draw=black, thin, rectangle, minimum width=7pt, fill=white, 
                font=\scriptsize}}
        
        \node[morphlabel] at (0,0) {$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    
    \node (1) at (0,0){\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```